# How to place Ember root template into specific location

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

There's a ton of great Ember examples out there, but they all seem to only show Ember templates rendering on a sandbox DOM with no actual `HTML` or `BODY` tags. It shows how to get the templates linked up to each other nicely, but leaves out one major question:

How do I put the root Ember template into specific place on my page's DOM?

I've seen the `appendTo()` function in the docs, but that seems wrong and hacky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass element `id` attribute to `rootElement` in your Application upon creation:

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
rootElement : "#ember-application-root",
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="ember-application-root"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Extra notes can be found in [source code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-pre.2/packages/ember-application/lib/system/application.js#L188)

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the answer. Now that I've got the answer I was able to find it in the docs, but it eluded me beforehand.